# How to write a enum that would take generics variable

Tags: java, generics, caching, enums, singleton

I have a usecase to create a Singleton cache using enum. The key and value of the cache should be generic variable.

Enum in java do not directly take generic variables. Not perfectly sure if that can be done if implementing an interface. Although it works to an extent if we provide the datatype in place of generics variables. To explain this. The below code is fine without compilation error.

```
public enum MyCache implements Cache<String, String> {


INSTANCE;

@Override
public void putIntoMyCache(String dK, String dV) {
        domainDataCache.put(dK, dV);
}
@Override
public Optional<String> getFromMyCache(String dK) {
    return domainDataCache.get(dK);
}

private  DomainDataCache<String, String> domainDataCache = new DomainDataCache();


}


public interface Cache<Key,Value> {
    public void putIntoLgiCache(Key dK, Value dV);
    public Optional<Value> getFromLgiCache(Key dK);
}
```

In the above code we implemented Cache interface using

```
Cache<String, String>
```

which works. But I need to have a

```
cache<Key,Value>
```

whose key and value needs to be generic variable,

I have no clue if this is possible in java!!

Thanks in advance Guys!!

Comment: You tried to use Object instead of String, I never tried anything similar, but should work

Comment: Why would you need those to be generic variables? You have a singleton, so there's only going to be one instance of it. So you would know the types (such as `<String, String>`) in advance.

Comment: With Singleton, i am making sure that there is single instance of it. But with generics i am making design flexible so as to take any key and value. I can change the key and value in later point of time as needed. I dont have to make change in the cache enum. @Kayaman

Comment: @Nilotpal that's not how it works. You can't change those "later". Your entire code will depend on the types you choose now, and you'll have to choose suitable types. If you want to allow the most flexibility, you'll have to go with `<Object, Object>` and resort to casting in your code. If you had multiple instances, then you could determine the type on creation, as with any typed class, but you have a single instance.